# transform.Rotate causing fps drop on android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Using transform.Rotate on game objects with a collider and a sprite renderer is causing the game to lag on Android. Any thoughts on how to improve this?

I've tried disabling the colliders and adding a rigidbody set to kinematic, as mentioned in another post but to no avail.

Here's the components of the rotating objects:

[image]

and here is the script used to rotate:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Rotate
    float speed = 150.0f;
    public bool forward = false;
    public bool back = false;
    public bool down = false;
    public bool up = false;
    public bool right = false;
    public bool left = false;


    void Update()
    {
        //Rotate
        if(forward == true)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (back == true)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.back * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (down == true)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.down * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (up == true)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (right == true)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (left == true)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }


}
```

So I basically manually change the bool to true/false in the inpsector to manage which direction I want the game object to rotate. Is there another way of doing this without causing such low fps? On PC it drops as well but it's not noticable.

Comment: This is the simplest of tasks. It should not create issues. Probably something else is going on.

Comment: Are you sure it's the rotation? Try profiling your game, see what's causing the delay. You can open the profiler via the "Window" menu in the editor.

Comment: Yes i'm pretty sure it's the rotation. As the other levels(scenes) run at 60 fps and when i added more objects with this script the fps just got lower, at around 25-30 fps with about 15 of these game objects.

Comment: The profiler shows frequent spikes of "Garbage Collector" and "Script" is also going up when i add these game objects. Without them it only shows one big spike but not at all as frequent. With rotation: https://imgur.com/a/FpRMhgq

Comment: How are you adding these objects? also can you remove rigidbody and try?

Comment: Also tried disabling static just to be sure but nothing changed.

Comment: The game objects are in the scene as obstacles to avoid. They are there from the beginning as children to an empty parent game object for hierarchy structure. I tried removing rigidbody but the fps is still the same.

Comment: What type of collider are you using? Is it a polygon collider with many points? If so, try replacing them with a circle collider and see if anything changs. (Oops I didn't see the image before).

Comment: Only using Box Collider 2D.

Answer (score 0):

As some people mentioned in the comments, it was another part of the script that did made the fps drop. I thought it wasn't even being executed at the time but apparently it was. My bad. Thanks for the help!